# How to get job and telescope command on chrome's V8 x64.release version? (No symbol "_v8_internal_Print_Object" in current context)

Tags: google-chrome, security, v8, exploit, embedded-v8

I'm trying to get chrome's V8 (d8) `x64.release` version to use the V8 support tools in GDB, specifically for the `job` and `telescope` commands (predominantly the former).

My `x64.debug` version has this implemented and works, but even after building the `x64.release` version in a similar manner I still cannot get these commands to work in the `x64.release` version. The output is always as:

```
gef➤  job 0xd98082f7b51
No symbol "_v8_internal_Print_Object" in current context.
```

I have set args.gn before, and after building via `ninja -C` to include `v8_enable_object_print = true` in my `args.gn`:

```
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_goma = false
v8_enable_object_print = true
v8_enable_disassembler = true
```

I also have my `~/.gdbinit` containing:

```
source ~/Desktop/tools/v8/tools/gdbinit
source ~/Desktop/tools/v8/tools/gdb-v8-support.py
```

See: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/tools/gdbinit (for the support tool I'm trying to build V8 with).

How can I get my `/v8/out.gn/x64.release/d8` to run with compatibility of the `job` command?

Am I missing something here? If so your help would be very helpful.

**EDIT** Alternatively how can I disable all `x64.debug` V8 DCHECKS?

Thanks all, appreciate your time here.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get my `/v8/out.gn/x64.release/d8` to run with compatibility of the `job` command?

I'm not sure. Try adding `symbol_level = 1` (or even `symbol_level = 2`) to your `args.gn`. That definitely helps with stack traces, and might also be the thing that lets GDB find the `_v8_internal_Print_Object` function by name.

> Alternatively how can I disable all `x64.debug` V8 DCHECKS?

There is no flag to disable them, but you can edit the source to make them do nothing. See `src/base/logging.h`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. However I have finally solved the problem!